# Configuration file "/var/lib/sddm/.config/sddm-greeterrc" not writable is displayed when booting to KDE

Tags: linux, arch-linux, kde, plasma, sddm

I have KDE-Plasma on Arch. I recently changed my DE from Gnome to KDE because of some gdm issues. Everything is working great but while booting, a dialogue shows this prompt. Pressing Enter boots up the system normally but I want to know why this prompt is being shown and how can this be removed.

```
Configuration file "/var/lib/sddm/.config/sddm-greeterrc" not writable. Please contact your system administrator.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the issue by changing the owner of the `/var/lib/sddm/.config/` directory recursively. The owner for the directory was root.

```
chown sddm:sddm /var/lib/sddm/.config -R
```

or

```
chown -R sddm:sddm /var/lib/sddm/.config
```

Answer (score 1):

Got the same issue on my install.

Just `touch` the file at that address:

```
touch /var/lib/sddm/.config/sddm-greeterrc
```